# Android app not reacting to UI change from UI thread

Tags: android, user-interface

I have a strange problem with android UI. I have simple test application when I want to check capabilities of Bluetooth connection. I implemented kind of ping-pong service, and I wanted to illustrate ping-pong activity on the screen. To do that I placed there EditText field, made it uneditable and left there to switch between X and + char continuously, once ping-pong messages are exchanged. That's the background of my story.

I got stuck with illustrating the activity on the screen (which I really would like to know how to do).

This is the code performing the switch:

```
public void switchConnectionIndicator(){
    if(SteeringScreen.lastConnectionPing > SteeringScreen.lastScreenUpdate) {
        SteeringScreen.lastScreenUpdate = System.currentTimeMillis();
        EditText connection = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.connectionInd);
        System.out.println("Switch to "+(connection.getText().toString().equals("X") ? "+" : "X"));
        connection.setText(connection.getText().toString().equals("X") ? "+" : "X");
    }
}
```

Method is located in same class as main UI screen, and is triggered by sensor events to provide continues screen refresh (I know, it's dirty, but I just wanted to get it working). Ping-pong activity works, as I got following output in console:

```
12-31 00:49:47.738  I/System.out: Switch to X
12-31 00:49:48.245  I/System.out: Switch to +
12-31 00:49:48.745  I/System.out: Switch to X
12-31 00:49:49.245  I/System.out: Switch to +
12-31 00:49:49.769  I/System.out: Switch to X
12-31 00:49:50.277  I/System.out: Switch to +
12-31 00:49:50.777  I/System.out: Switch to X
12-31 00:49:51.285  I/System.out: Switch to +
12-31 00:49:51.808  I/System.out: Switch to X
```

I went with debugger to check exact moment of switch in EditText component, and this bastard is getting right value on each event. The only thing is missing is to SEE RESULT ON THE SCREEN, where it stays unchanged. Does anyone has any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: show full code of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I'm not sure where your method is called from, so make sure that setText is happening on the UI thread (there's not always a crash when it's not), you can use the following inside the method, to force it

```
context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { 
    @Override
    public void run() {
        connection.setText(...);
    }
};
```

You also mention "sensor events to provide continues screen refresh". I'm not sure what you mean you are doing with this but make sure you are not reinflating anything (and thus making your references to the connection view out of date)

Comment: Well, the flow of triggering the refresh is the following - view is in the same time listener for sensor changes, and I attached it to accelerometer - which is almost constantly registering some change. Each time sensor changes, it triggers method I showed you. I assume that method executes on right thread, because for example if you are reading values from accelerometer, you can instantly print them into dome textview, and it refreshed on screen (does it, right?). So my handling of this event is nearly the same. I'll check UI thread hint you gave me.

Answer (score -1):

I managed to modify my code in a way that it works. The only thing I am missing here is why it worked :D
When I changed static variables:

- SteeringScreen.lastConnectionPing
- SteeringScreen.lastScreenUpdate

to local, private ones, it started to work. Is there some secret feature of Java I don't know of? Can someone explain it to me?